# Best way to take all querystring pairs and init a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to store all the key/value pairs in my querystring:

```
www.example.com/?a=2&b=3&c=34
```

into a dictionary.  Is there a quick way of doing this w/o having to manually cycle through all the items?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`.

It gives you back a `NameValueCollection` of your keys and values.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about HttpUtility.  (But I think it is because it's in System.Web, a namespace that I'm not so familiar with).

Comment: Also then you could use NameValueCollectionExtensions.CopyTo(this NameValueCollection, IDictionary<<string, object>>) to get a "real" IDictionary.

Comment: Blah... A single "greater than" sign in the comments doesn't work. Comments on SO needs some improvements.

Comment: @JohannesH This works too: `var nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
    var qsDic = nv.Cast<object>().ToDictionary<object, string, object>(key => (string) key, key => nv[(string) key]);`

Answer (score 0):

Get the string that is found after the question mark, split the string on the '&' character.
Then, for each string that is being returned, split again on the '=' character.

You could even create an extension method for it.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{

    public Dictionary<string, string> ExtractQueryStringValues( this string target )
    {

        string queryString = target.Split (target.IndexOf ('?') + 1);

        string[] keyvaluePairs = queryString.Split ('&');

        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach( string pair in keyvaluePairs )
        {
             var tmp = pair.Split ('=');

             result.Add (tmp[0], tmp[1]);
        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

Something like that.
Remember, it is not safe, as it does not handle each edge-case.  (For instance, given a string that has nothing after the first question mark, etc...), but it should get you started.