# Is it possible to split a string into a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is it possible to split a string by '&' and init a dictionary in one go or you have to use a string array first?

I want to take the url part:

?a=2&b=3

and load a `dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: Do you mean into a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`? What would be the key and what would be the value?

Comment: Hey Sean,  look at this previous question... :P

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180004/best-way-to-take-all-querystring-pairs-and-init-a-dictionary

Comment: There are builtin methods for this

Comment: Sorry, but what is the purpose of posting exactly the same question two times?? Looks like spam..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of your own question...

[Best way to take all querystring pairs and init a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180004/best-way-to-take-all-querystring-pairs-and-init-a-dictionary)

As womp said, HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() is your best bet.

**Edit:**
After doing a little digging I found the following extension method NameValueCollectionExtensions.CopyTo(this NameValueCollection, IDictionary< string, object >) that you could use to populate a true IDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the format given, I think you want something like this:

```
var dict = queryString
    .Substring(1) // to skip the "?"
    .Split("&")
    .Select(s => s.Split("="))
    .ToDictionary(sa => sa[0], sa => sa[1]);
```

Comment: Actually, the library method JohannesH mentions is probably a better bet.